# endfloat leaves space even when marker text off

Tags: tables, floats, positioning, endfloat

I am using `endfloat` to process all my tables at the end of my document. I am also using the option to suppress in-text markers. However, `endfloat` still seems to insert a space where the marker would have been (in effect creating an unnecessary space between my paragraphs). The reason this is happening is because of the centering tags. Removing them fixes the problem. Why does this happen?
MWE:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[nolists,tablesfirst,nomarkers]{endfloat}


\begin{document}
Some text here Some text here Some text here Some text here Some text
here Some text here Some text here Some text here Some text here Some
text here Some text here Some text here Some text here Some text here
Some text here Some text here Some text here Some text here Some text
here Some text here Some text here Some text here Some text here Some
text here Some text here Some text here Some text here Some text here
Some text here 

\begin{center}
\begin{table}
\protect\caption{My Table}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline 
a &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\hline 
 & b &  &  & \tabularnewline
\hline 
 &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
\hline 
 &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
\hline 
 &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\par\end{center}

Some more text here Some more text here Some more text here Some more
text here Some more text here Some more text here Some more text here
Some more text here Some more text here Some more text here Some more
text here Some more text here Some more text here Some more text here
Some more text here Some more text here Some more text here Some more
text here Some more text here Some more text here 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please edit your question so that it includes a complete example code that reproduces the problem. Without this it may be difficult for anyone to help you.

Comment: i am attempting to come up with one but it is not easy

Comment: I tried as well, but it's even harder for me, since I've never seen the problem!

Comment: got it. mwe added; the solution to the original question is to remove the centering and then all the spacing looks fine. the question is why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That space is caused by `center` environment. The `center` environment is defined as a `trivlist` (or simply as a `list`)

```
\def\center{\trivlist \centering\item\relax}
\def\endcenter{\endtrivlist}
```

As you can see, it is a `\trivlist` around `\centering`. The effect of `\trivlist` is to add  `\topsep`, `\partopsep` etc. For the definitions of these things, please refer to `latex.ltx`. In conclusion, the `center` environment adds vertical space above and below, which, in some cases (like this) is unnecessary.

Further, the table contained inside the `center` environment floats (to be put at the end), but the `center` environment stays where it is. The white space (associated with `center` environment) stays too at the original position and the `table` will be out of `center` environment and hence won't be centered.

Avoid those spaces by using just `\centering`.

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[nolists,tablesfirst,nomarkers]{endfloat}


\begin{document}
Some text here Some text here Some text here Some text here Some text
here Some text here Some text here Some text here Some text here Some
text here Some text here Some text here Some text here Some text here
Some text here Some text here Some text here Some text here Some text
here Some text here Some text here Some text here Some text here Some
text here Some text here Some text here Some text here Some text here
Some text here

%\begin{center}
\begin{table}
\caption{My Table}    %% no need of \protect use \caption[short title] instead

\centering         %%<--- here
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
a &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
\hline
\hline
 & b &  &  & \tabularnewline
\hline
 &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
\hline
 &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
\hline
 &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

%\par\end{center}

Some more text here Some more text here Some more text here Some more
text here Some more text here Some more text here Some more text here
Some more text here Some more text here Some more text here Some more
text here Some more text here Some more text here Some more text here
Some more text here Some more text here Some more text here Some more
text here Some more text here Some more text here
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks. I have modified the answer. Feel free to edit if needed.

Comment: explanation is nice and clear, no edits needed.